# JavaScript Revealing Prototype Pattern - Assigning XML Data to an Object Variable

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, javascript-objects, prototype-oriented

---

## Introduction

---

I'm building world-wide conference room directory using a XML data set. I want to tuck the data in the `this.formData` so that I can reuse that info in multiple ways without having to call the XML again and again.

`this.formData` is *undefined* as I step through the debugger

What am I doing wrong?

---

## The Code

---

```
var Directory = function () {
    this.formData;
};

Directory.prototype = function () {

    init = function () {
        getXMLforDropDown.call(this);
        buildDropDown.call(this);
    },
    getXMLforDropDown = function () {

        var directoryObj = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'formdata/crooms.xml',
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xmlData) {

               directoryObj.formData = xmlData;

            }
        });
    },
    buildDropDown = function () {
        if ($('#ddChooseCountry')) {
            $('#ddChooseCountry').append($('<option value=""></option>'));
            $(this.formData).find('room').each(function () {
                var strCountry = ($(this).attr('country'));
                if (strCountry !== "") {
                    $('#ddChooseCountry').append($('<option value="' + strCountry + '">' + StrCountry + '</option>'));
                }
            });
        }
    }


    return {
        init: init
    }
} ();



$(document).ready(function () {

    var directory = new Directory() ;
    directory.init();

});
```

---

Comment: `buildDropdown` is being called too early. Ajax is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making an asynchronous http request, so your `buildDropDown` method gets called too early. You could try setting an ajax option to make it a synchronous request.

```
$.ajax({
  async: false, // yay for sync
  url: 'formdata/crooms.xml',
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function (xmlData) {
    directoryObj.formData = xmlData;
  }
});
```

Alternatively you could just call `buildDropDown` inside of your success handler.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'formdata/crooms.xml',
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function(xmlData) {
    directoryObj.formData = xmlData;
    directoryObj.buildDropDown();
  }
});
```

Comment: Worked perfect!  Thank you for the explanation. Yay for sync indeed!